# Make a checkbox send to database

Tags: php, database, forms, checkbox

How do I send checkbox to datase?

Some of my code: *(I think everything exept checkbox works)*

```
<label for="year">Question</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="2014" value="2014"><span class="cb">2013/2014</span><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="2015" value="2015"><span class="cb">2014/2015</span><br/>
```

*CODES*

```
if( isset($_POST['save'])) {

    if( $_POST['year']!="" ){
```

*CODES*

*CONNECTS*

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO vakt(year)
            VALUES('".$_POST['year']."') ";
```

Comment: Use a js function that store checkbox value to a hidden textbox (use document.getElementById to store), and from php fetch that value using a simple form .

Comment: Your biggest problem is blindly inserting user-submitted data into your database, making you vulnerable to SQL injection.  Fix that first, and you should have a pretty good idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all checkboxes the same name value, with [] at the end:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="years[]" value="2014"><span class="cb">2013/2014</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="years[]" value="2015"><span class="cb">2014/2015</span><br/>
```

Then you can get the selected years as an array in php:

```
foreach($_POST['years'] as $year) {
    // Insert $year into database
}
```

Please make sure you correctly escape any user submitted data for security reasons